# Fire Datalist OnItemDataBound event on Dropdown SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, datalist

Is it possible to fire Datalist OnItemDataBound event on Dropdown SelectedIndexChanged ???

I am trying through following code but it is doing nothing :

```
protected void drpTopic_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dlSubjects.ItemDataBound +=new DataListItemEventHandler(dlSubjects_ItemDataBound);
}

protected void dlSubjects_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
       // Some Code...
}
```

Please Help me to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

In your `SelectedIndexChange` rebind your datalist because it will automatically fire `ItemDataBound` event